# Join and Alias Issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im taking the Google Data analytics course and I was following along but I'm getting an error that i do not understand.

An error comes up saying it does not the recognize the column in both table but when i check the schema on both its obviously there. Can i get some help? Did I enter this in wrong or am i missing something?

This is a snip of the issue from BigQuery:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tUPs.png)

Query is below:

```
SELECT
 orders.*,
 warehouse.warehouse alias,
 warehouse.state
FROM
 `true-ability-380223.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` AS orders
INNER JOIN 
`true-ability-380223.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id;
```

I'm trying to get data from both tables to join together.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the alias on the second table:

```sql
SELECT
  orders.*, 
  warehouse.warehouse alias,
  warehouse.state
FROM 
  `true-ability-380223.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` AS orders
INNER JOIN
  `true-ability-380223.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` AS warehouse
ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias your second table '`true-ability-380223.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` as warehouse.